# не получается вернуть метод

Tags: java

Не получается вернуть метод. В чем ошибка?

Если нужно, вот задача:

> Даны два числа - n и m. Создайте двумерный массив A[n][m], заполните
>   его таблицей умножения A[i][j]=i*j и выведите на экран. При этом
>   нельзя использовать вложенные циклы, все заполнение массива должно
>   производиться одним циклом.
>
> **Входные данные**
>   Программа получает на вход два числа n и m – количество строк и столбцов, соответственно.
>
> **Выходные данные**
>   Программа должна вывести  полученный массив. Под каждое число отводите четыре знакоместа. Например, число 8 должно быть
>   напечатано с тремя пробелами перед ним.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyProgram {

    public static int line(int i, int j, int a[][]) {
        int [] [] A = new int [n] [m];
        for (j = 0; j < A[i][j].length; j++) {
            A[i][j] = i * j;
        }
        return A[][];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt(), m = in.nextInt();
        int a[][] = new int[n][m];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            line(i, j, a[][]);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < a[i].length; k++) {
                System.out.println(a[i][k]);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "вернуть метод"?

Comment: Вы сообщения компилятора читаете? В строке `int [] [] A = new int [n] [m];` что такое `n` и `m` и откуда они берутся, по вашему? В следующей строке `A[i][j].length` -- что это такое? В последней строке метода `line` -- `return A[][]` -- что это такое, что метод возвращает? Дальше я просто не стал читать. И да, "вернуть метод" -- такого понятия вообще нет, метод нельзя вернуть. Очень советую почитать какую-нибудь начальную книжку по `Java`, прежде чем пытаться что-то писать.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void line(int k, int a[][], int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i][k] = i * k;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt(), m = in.nextInt();
        int a[][] = new int[n][m];
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            line(i, a,n);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < a[i].length; k++) {
                System.out.println(a[i][k]);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Regent по заданию сказано, что не должно быть вложенных циклов, насчет того что не должен возвращать а - я с вами полностью с вами согласен, я бы сделал его глобальной статической матрицей ( а так я просто подправил код, остальное пусть все делает автор). A[i][j]=i*j, а не a[i][j] = (i + 1) * (j + 1); насчет этой строчки - отчет начинается с 0!!! 4 пункт автора сделает сам, я к этому даже не притрагивался!\ 5 - то же с вами согласен. но опять же я просто подправил автора

Comment: @Regent автор должен сам разбираться почему мы можем не возвращать матрицу,как правильно выводить матрицу, как сделать эту задачу с помощью одного цикла и т д. можно кидать тревогу

Answer (score 0):

вы хотите вернуть из метода массив. поэтому надо объявить в начале метода, что вы хотите вернуть, а вернуть только переменную. (наверное объяснил непонятно, поэтом ловите кусок вашего кода)

p.s. код не смотрел, просто ответил на сам вопрос "почему не возвращается массив из метода"

```
   public static int [][] line(int i, int j, int a[][]) {
        int [] [] A = new int [n] [m];
        for (j = 0; j < A[i][j].length; j++) {
            A[i][j] = i * j;
        }
        return A;
    }
```

Comment: Эмм, а что насчет того факта, что `n` и `m` не определены, и ваш код не скомпилируется?

Comment: а что насчет p.s. код не смотрел, просто ответил на сам вопрос "почему не возвращается массив из метода"

Comment: да и можно ли вообще реализацию задачи считать верной, если в цикле вызывается метод, в котором другой цикл, а написано "БЕЗ вложенных циклов"

Comment: Неа, нельзя, в соседнем ответе уже это обсуждали. Просто было бы здорово, чтобы код из ответа хотя бы компилировался

Comment: сейчас допишу условие про "4 знака-места" и выкину решение

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // введем наши N, M и создадим матрицу по ним
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        int [][]A = new int [n][m];
        // объявим наши индексы
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        // вместо классик вложенных for{for{...}} будем использовать do-while, где будем сами проgисывать действия циклов for
        do{
            A[i][j] = i*j; // умножаем и записываем число

            // теперь займемся условием по "4 знак-место"
            int space = 4; // у нас есть 4 места, куда мы можем разместить наше число
            double a = A[i][j]; // копия нашего числа. через него будем узнавать, сколько пробелов надо
            do{
                a /= 10; // делим наше число на 10
                space--; // у уменьшаем кол-во нужных пробелов
            }while (a>=1); // пока наше число не будет <1
            probel(space); // вызываем метод, который поставит нужное кол-во пробелов

            System.out.print(A[i][j]); // наконец записываем само число
            j++; // увеличим индекс на 1
            if (j>=m){ // сделаем проверку "мы вышли за пределы матрицы?", и если ответ ДА
                j=0; // обнулим этот индекс
                i++; // а этот увеличим
                System.out.println("\n"); // ну и начнем дальше с новой сстроки. у нас же "таблица"
            }
        }while (i<n); // и все это мы делаем пока 0<=i<n
        }

        // метод для пробелов. использовал точки, чтобы удобно было считать
        public static void probel(int space){ // передаем в метод наше кол-во пробелов
        for (int i=0; i<space; i++){ // делаем цикл на кол-во пробелов
            System.out.print("."); // и вписываем пробел
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: В принципе, если вместо `probel` использовать существующий формат строки, а `i` и `j` считать относительно "глобального" индекса, решение выйдет покороче: http://tpcg.io/rPkJaB. Там только неправильно написал `"% 04d"` - надо `"% 4d"`

Comment: ха!) классное решение с целым и остатком!